# How to create a partial clipping mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, mask

[image]

I want to create an image similar to this. 
How can I clip mask only half of the image into the object while the rest of half still stays in the full image?

In the attached image, half of the footballer's body is clipped into the bar graphs while the other half is still preserved.

This is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merely configure a **Layer Mask**. - White to show the parts you want and black to hide what you don't want visible.

[image]

If you are unclear on how to create **Layer Masks**, you may want to review the Adobe Help Documentation: **[Masking Layers](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html)**

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again, is there any video which does the same thing as your image. I understood the concept but I'm finding it hard to implement.

Comment: Uhm... there are videos at the link I posted above.

Answer (score -2):

this trick was something I also looking for, fortunately I found it after so much searching on many sites, It's called "Out of the Frame effect"

you'll find hundreds of videos in YouTube, so enjoy learning.