# Adding a color overlay to parts of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, image-editing

Can someone tell me what's used in this image? More exactly how that purple is added here?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a partial clipping mask?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81430/how-to-create-a-partial-clipping-mask)

Answer (score 0):

- add a new top layer, fill it with the wanted purple
- change the blending mode of the purple layer to "Color"
- erase the purple from those areas that you want stay in the original color

Here only a few areas are erased:

[image]

You can erase by the Eraser or selecting the area to be erased and by pressing DEL.

You can make selections by drawing the borderline using the polygonal lasso, lasso or clipping path. The last is the most accurate tool.

The semiautomatic selection tools like magic wand, quick selector or select by color are used in the photo layer, but the DEL is pressed in the purple layer

NOTE: You can also add purple by painting or by filling selected areas.

Making the selections is often a hard job due the wanted accuracy. In addition often is needed to make corrections afterwards. That's why professionals rather use layer masks. You should as soon as possible learn from the tutorials, how to

- add a layer mask to the purple layer
- how adding into the mask white makes areas fully visible, grey makes areas partially transparent and black makes areas fully transparent (=invisible)

Here the job is completed by using the layer mask. In this case there are no partial transparency, so the mask has only black and white.

[image]